# remove cache in hook_preprocess_node

Tags: 8, theming, entities, hooks

I'm using hook_preprocess_node to get node field and make some processes, then pass a variable to the node to use it in the node twig template. The problem with me that when I edit this node, it doesn't affect on the view, I have to clear cache to see this change on the node view.

```
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {

    if (isset($variables['elements']['#node'])) {
        $node = $variables['elements']['#node'];
        $bundle = $node->bundle();
    }
    if (isset($bundle) && $bundle == 'crse') {
        $course_schedules = array();
        foreach ($node->get('crse_sched') as $schedule_item) {
            $schedule_entity = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($schedule_item->target_id);
            $schedule = new stdClass();
            $schedule->title = $schedule_entity->get('title')->getValue()[0]['value'];
            $schedule->seats = $schedule_entity->get('seats')->getValue()[0]['value'];
            $schedule->state = $schedule_entity->get('moderation_state')->getValue()[0]['value'];
            $course_schedules[] = $schedule;
        }
        $variables['schedules'] = $course_schedules;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You have to add cache tags of all entities you get data from. Add this line to the foreach loop:

```
$variables['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node:' . $schedule_entity->id();
```

The parent node is already tagged, which would also happen for the schedule entities if rendered normally.

This is all you need to do, adding the tags of the entities you use to build the rendered output. The entity system invalidates cache items, which are tagged correctly, automatically on all CRUD operations.

Comment: that principle, but I'd recommend to use $schedule_entity->getCacheTags() and merge them together or even do something like `\Drupal::service('renderer')->addCacheableDependency($variables, $node);`

Comment: Yes, usually I prefer merging cacheable dependencies of objects too, but in this case I wanted to provide an answer as simple as possible, because I think when you see the tag itself you understand that the entity system can only invalidate items that include the tag of the entity which is modified.

Answer (score 3):

Every entity has cache tags to get the cache tags of the current entity use

```
$cache_tags = $entity->getCacheTags();
```

You need to invalidate the cache so you have to call

```
\Drupal\Core\Cache\Cache::invalidateTags($cache_tags);
```

Than the cache for these cache_tags will be invalidated.

Comment: Where is the `$entity` coming from?

Comment: Should come from your $variables array.
$entity = $variables['elements']['#node']; e.g.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your `hook_preprocess_node` to prevent it be cached

```
$variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `THEME_preprocess_node` hook you can add the below code to disable the variable  cache for particular content type.

```
if($variables['node']->getType() == 'content_type_machine_name') {
    $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```