# Get a session value in a template file

Tags: 8, sessions

I am trying to get value set in session in a template file, but I don't get the expected value. I tried two methods, but neither of them works for me.

The code in the custom module controller is the following.

```
$xyz ='tets';
$session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
//$session->set('xyz', $roles);
$session->set('abc', $xyz);
```

The code in the template file is the following.

```
{% set varname = app.session.get('abc') %}
{{ varname }}
```

I tried using the following code as well.

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$tempstore->set('num_donateur', $num_donateur);
```

Comment: Pass the variable in in your template_preprocess() function.

Comment: do I need use $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession(); in template_preprocess()
function template_preprocess(&$variables, $hook){
    $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
    $variables['abc'] =  $session->get('abc');

}

Comment: you can use user.private_tempstore. And use the respective preprocess function based on in which template file you need the value. for example: if you need in ´node.html.twig´ then use ´yourtheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) { }´function.

Comment: You usually set a session value in a POST request. When doing it in a controller you have to disable caching for this controller. When displaying the session value like in your comment then add a cache context for the session to the render array. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/273752/47547

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by send session variable in theme template_preprocess and then call the variable in the twig file.

template.theme :-

```
template_preprocess($variables){
   $session = \Drupal::request()->getSession();
   $variables['abc'] = $session->get('abc'); 
}
```

Call variable in twig file :-

```
{{ abc }}
```