# Session variable and cache drupal

Tags: 8, sessions

I've created a small helper where I can set and access my session variable (thanks to the drupal 8 session).

Can't figure out why, my session is working well with my dev (no cache) but on my prod my session is not persisted, need to refresh drupal cache to see my session variable...

```
  public static function getSessionIRA()
  {
    return self::getModuleStore()->get('session_ira');
  }

  public static function setSessionIRA($session_ira)
  {
    return self::getModuleStore()->set('session_ira', $session_ira);
  }

  /**
   * @return mixed
   */
  private static function getModuleStore()
  {
    return \Drupal::request()->getSession();

    return self::$module_store = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_services');
  }
```

UPDATE:

I had to add my development settings on my production website, but I believe that it's not recommanded... How can I avoid this ?

See my config below on my prod environment

```
parameters:
  http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
  twig.config:
    debug: false
    auto_reload: true

services:
  cache.backend.null:
    class: Drupal\Core\Cache\NullBackendFactory
```

Comment: See my comment on a similar question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/296825/get-a-session-value-in-a-template-file#comment376099_296825

Comment: I've did this too, but this isn't working unfortunately...